# ImageEditor.cropImage issue with React Native in Android

Tags: react-native

I want to crop image in react native and using the below code,

```
var cropData = {
    offset: {x: 0, y: 20},
    size: {width: 20, height: 20},
    displaySize: {width: 20, height: 20},
    resizeMode: 'contain',
};

ImageEditor.cropImage(
    uripath,
    cropData,
    (croppedImageURI) => {
        console.log('succes', croppedImageURI);
    },
    (cropError) => {
        console.log('fail', cropError);
    }
);
```

In iOS, its working fine.

In andorid, i'm getting the below error

**java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String getString**

Please help!

Comment: Have you found any solution to this poblem?